# How to verify if the particular element is Not Clickable in Selenide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenide

Need to verify element is not able click or Not Clickable using Selenide

Comment: Just a suggestion. Single line questions with no context can't explain what you're talking about, so nobody can answer it. For example, I have no idea what lead you to ask this question, what your code looks like or if any exception is thrown. I suggest you post a question with a somewhat detailed description, the code and exceptions and be concise

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.*;

// ...

SelenideElement el = ... // Look up element
el.shouldBe(not(and("Clickable", visible, enabled)));
```

This is much like how `ExpectedConditions` detects if an element is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a check for text elements that uses Selenide and Junit Assertions.

It basically checks whether there exists a link on a page that contains given text.

```
boolean hasLink = $x("//a[contains(text(), 'some text that is not a link')]").exists();
Assertions.assertFalse(hasLink);
```